# ThisWorkbook.save expected function or variable

Tags: excel, vba, compilation

I'm receiving a compilation error in the VBA code for an Excel macro.  I had a look for any previous questions on the site relating to this but none of the previous examples appear to apply to my case and the solutions are varied so I'm posting here in the hope of finding a more specific answer.

When trying to compile my code I get an error on this line

```
With ThisWorkbook
    .Save = True 'Compilation error occurs here
    .Close
End With
```

The error reads

> Expected Function or variable

I don't understand why this is the case as after I type ThisWorkbook Intellisense gives me the option of Save as a valid function.

Comment: `.Save` is a `Method`, not a `Property`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove `= True` from the `Save`. However, you can achieve the same thing in one line like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the = true

Just thisworkbook.save